# Restricting Roboflow model inference to a user-defined region in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using a Roboflow model to detect pool balls in a video feed. The video feed is processed using OpenCV and the model is running on an OpenAI Kit (OAK) device. The model and device are interfaced using the roboflowoak package.

I want to add a feature where the user can draw a rectangle on the video feed, and the model will only detect pool balls within this rectangle. Essentially, anything outside this rectangle should be ignored by the model.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
from roboflowoak import RoboflowOak

# global variables
ix, iy = -1, -1
drawing = False
rect_over = False
x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = -1, -1, -1, -1

# mouse callback function
def draw_rectangle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global ix, iy, drawing, rect_over, x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix, iy = x, y
        x_start, y_start = x, y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            x_end, y_end = x, y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        rect_over = True
        x_end, y_end = x, y

def main():
    # Instantiate RoboflowOak object
    rf = RoboflowOak(
        model="billiards-y0wwp",
        confidence=0.05,
        overlap=0.2,
        version="3",
        api_key="My API Key",
        rgb=True,
        depth=True,
        device=None,
        blocking=True
    )

    # create named window to attach mouse callback function
    cv2.namedWindow('frame')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('frame', draw_rectangle)

    # Loop to continuously run model inference and display output
    while True:
        t0 = time.time()

        # Run model inference
        result, frame, raw_frame, depth = rf.detect()

        # Draw rectangle on frame
        if rect_over:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, pt1=(x_start, y_start), pt2=(x_end, y_end), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)

        # Filter out detections that are outside of the rectangle
        if rect_over:
            filtered_predictions = []
            for p in result['predictions']:
                bbox = p['bbox']  # Assuming the prediction has a 'bbox' key
                x_center = bbox['left'] + bbox['width'] / 2
                y_center = bbox['top'] + bbox['height'] / 2
                if x_start < x_center < x_end and y_start < y_center < y_end:
                    filtered_predictions.append(p)

            # Replace predictions with filtered predictions
            result['predictions'] = filtered_predictions

        # Print inference time
        print(f"INFERENCE TIME IN MS: {1 / (time.time() - t0)}")

        # Print predictions
        print(f"PREDICTIONS: {[p for p in result['predictions']]}")

        # Normalize depth for visualization
        max_depth = np.amax(depth)
        normalized_depth = depth / max_depth

        # Show depth and frame
        cv2.imshow("depth", normalized_depth)
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

        # Exit loop on 'q' key press
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, I've implemented a mouse callback to draw the rectangle, and I'm filtering out detections outside this rectangle after the inference. However, I feel this might not be the most efficient way since the model is still processing the entire frame.

Comment: Consider the following: your alternative would be to 'crop' each frame or set a capture region based on your rectangle, pad the frame to be the same expected size as your model and infer again on the same sized image where original = cropped+padding. You are doing the right thing.

Comment: @JasonChia, Thank You for your feedback I can not figure out how to make the rectangle visible, I would like to be able to add like a drag gesture on each corner to adjust its size in the future but I am completely stuck by not being able to see the rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

class test_class():

    def __init__(self):
# global variables # We dont like global variables
# Initiate class variables
        self.ix, self.iy = -1, -1
        self.drawing = False
        self.rect_over = False
        self.x_start, self.y_start, self.x_end, self.y_end = -1, -1, -1, -1
        
        self.toggle = False # INitialize our 'inference' toggle
        self.frame = np.zeros((250,250,3), np.uint8) #Dummy image


# mouse callback function
    def draw_rectangle(self,event, x, y, flags, param):
       
       

        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            self.drawing = True
            self.ix, self.iy = x, y
            self.x_start, self.y_start = x, y

        elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            if self.drawing == True:
                self.x_end, self.y_end = x, y

        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            self.drawing = False
            self.rect_over = True
            self.x_end, self.y_end = x, y

    def inference(self): # Dummy Inferencing function. 
        #you can put all your AI /filtering here
        print("I am running AI stuff")
        time.sleep(5)
        return
        
    def main(self):

        cv2.namedWindow('frame')
        cv2.setMouseCallback('frame', self.draw_rectangle)

        # Loop to continuously run model inference and display output
        while True:
            t0 = time.time()
            f_copy = self.frame.copy() #Copying my blank image as I don't have your stream
            # Run model inference
            #result, frame, raw_frame, depth = rf.detect()
            if self.toggle is True: 
                self.inference()
            # Draw rectangle on frame
            if self.rect_over:
                print("im here")
                cv2.rectangle(f_copy, pt1=(self.x_start, self.y_start), pt2=(self.x_end, self.y_end), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)

            cv2.imshow("frame", f_copy)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('f'): #probably a better way to do this. Cant exactly interrupt the inferencing step.....
                self.toggle = not self.toggle # Simple boolean toggle
            # Exit loop on 'q' key press
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_program = test_class()
    my_program.main()
```

Point 1: Avoid globals as its not recommended

Point 2: Consider toggling your inferencing while you are adjusting your box. Inferencing is acting as a blocker so you can barely see anything due to the delay.

Point 3. Not sure if you wanted to have a real time square as you are drawing the box

I created a dummmy image and a dummy function for the AI inferencing. Note the delay in the prints when you toggle it on. This also affects the callback for your 'box drawing'. Hence a probably good idea to do it separately and not concurrently. If you really want to do the adjustment at the same time as the inferencing; you probably have to look at multithreading/multiprocessing.